# Perl: convert string to a C string literal

Tags: c, perl

How can I use Perl to convert an arbitrary string to a valid, human readable
C string literal (i.e. something that can be put into C source and understood by the C compiler)?

Bonus points for solution requiring only core modules.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = get_some_string();    # Read string from file, database, network etc
my $cstr = ???($str);
print "const char *str = $cstr;" # This has to form valid C statement
```

Example output:

```
const char *str = "Hello, \"C\" string\n";
```

Comment: C will aceept that string unchanged. If you want something more then you must specify exactly what may appear in the string and how you want it displayed

Comment: I mean generate that string in Perl. I forgot to mention that in question body (although it was mentioned in title and tagged) - see my edit.

Comment: What's wrong with `print qq{const char *str = "Hello, world\\n";\n};`?

Comment: That's saying that you don't appear to have a program that you can't get to work, and that you need help with. Your question is also overly vague and I doubt if you are going to get a useful answer until it is clear in your own mind what you really need

Comment: Okay, and what have you tried that doesn't work? Is your string always 7-bit ASCII? Will the stuff from `get_string` contain escapes like you originally said `\110\145\154\154\157\054\040\167\157\162\154\144\012`? I'm surprised at you writing a junk question like this with a reputation of 11K

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = q/Hello, "C" string/ . "\n";
$str =~ s/(\W)/sprintf('\\%03o',ord($1))/ge;
print "const char *str = \"$str\";"
```

The RegEx matches every char except `a-z A-Z 0-9 _` and converts it to a octal value. You could easily replace `(\W)` by any more specific match like `([^a-zA-Z0-9,\.\-])` (match everything except `a-z A-Z 0-9 , . -`) or `([\x00-\x1f])` (match every ASCII code less than 30 = space).

A shorter solution would be:

```
$str =~ s/(["'`])/\\$1/g;
```

But that one would only escape quotation marks with a `\` prefix. All other chars which might cause trouble get through without replacement.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that Perl provides [`B::cstring`](http://perldoc.perl.org/B.html#Miscellaneous-Utility-Functions) function for this exact purpose:

> **cstring(STR)**
>
> Returns a double-quote-surrounded escaped version of STR which can be
>   used as a string in C source code.

```
print B::cstring(q/hi "C" string/)
# prints "hi \"C\" string"
```

Comment: Can't beat ready-made library solutions. ;-)

Comment: I wouldn't be too happy to see this used in production code. It adds a huge chunk of code for the sake of one utility function. The module's description has this *"The B module supplies classes which allow a Perl program to delve into its own innards. It is the module used to implement the "backends" of the Perl compiler. Usage of the compiler does not require knowledge of this module: see the O module for the user-visible part. The B module is of use to those who want to write new compiler backends."*

Comment: I'd agree were it external module. But `B` is a core module implemented as XS. My simple benchmarks show that performance impact is negligible.

Comment: nb. it provides also `perlstring` function which produces Perl string literal.

Comment: Maybe, but would you be happy to use, say, `XML::Twig::XPath` if you found that it just happened to contain a `cstring`? This just isn't what the `B` module is meant for

Comment: if `XML::Twig::XPath` was already being used by my application, i'd use it for `cstring`. And, IMO that's the case with `B` - all those `SV`s, `PV`s et al are already in Perl interpreter (that's what makes Perl work, after all), and `B` merely gives access to those objects rfom Perl itself.

Comment: @Borodin See the `XString` module (Isolated String helpers from B)

Answer (score 1):

That will work fine as it is

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    printf("\110\145\154\154\157\054\040\167\157\162\154\144\012");
}
```

#### output

```
Hello, world
```